# PHP MongoDB manager exception for aggregate command: "Failed to decode document from the server."

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

**My Sample collection:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58dbc09b19d7a17e44201982"),
    "process_id" : "2-1490770330177",
    "contacts" : [
        {
            "party_id" : 6636,
            "completed" : true,
            "kind" : 1
        },
        {
            "party_id" : 139611,
            "completed" : true,
            "kind" : 1
        },
        {
            "party_id" : 32609,
            "completed" : true,
            "kind" : 1
        },

        {
            "party_id" : 49520,
            "completed" : false,
            "kind" : 1
        },
        {
            "party_id" : 204031,
            "completed" : false,
            "kind" : 1
        },
        {
            "party_id" : 204379,
            "completed" : false,
            "kind" : 1
        }
    ],
    "tags" : [
        1277
    ]
}
```

And When I test this document with RoboMongo via followig query:

```
db.getCollection('BatchTag').aggregate(
                        {'$match':{"process_id":'2-1490770330177'}},
                        {'$unwind':'$contacts'},
                        {'$match':{'contacts.completed':false}},
                        {'$group':{_id:'$_id','contacts':{'$push':'$contacts'}}}
    )
```

I've received this result.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58dbc09b19d7a17e44201982"),
    "contacts" : [
        {
            "party_id" : 49520,
            "completed" : false,
            "kind" : 1
        },
        {
            "party_id" : 204031,
            "completed" : false,
            "kind" : 1
        },
        {
            "party_id" : 204379,
            "completed" : false,
            "kind" : 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Bu When I execute some query on PHP. I've received **"Failed to decode document from the server."** exception.
My PHP code is here:

```
            $command = new Command([
                "aggregate"=>"BatchTag",
                "pipeline" => [
                    ['$match'=>["process_id"=>$processUID]],
                    ['$unwind'=>'$contacts'],
                    ['$match'=>['contacts.completed'=>false]],
                    ['$group'=>['_id'=>'$_id','contacts'=>['$push'=>'$contacts']]]
                ]
            ]);
            $rows = $this->getMongoManager()->executeCommand($this->container->getParameter("mongodb_db_name").".BatchTag",$command)->toArray();
```

I don't understand, what is wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing the collection name too to the [executeCommand](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executecommand.php).

You should only pass db name as `command` obj already has collection name.

Try something like

```
$rows = $this->getMongoManager()->executeCommand($this->container->getParameter("mongodb_db_name"),$command)->toArray();
```